# Refreshing a page on close of simple modal window

Tags: jquery, html, modal-dialog, eric-martin-modal

I am using eric martin's simple modal window. Just need to know how we can refresh a parent page on click of close button.

Here is my code for showing a popup,

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    $('#myModalDiv').modal({ dataCss: { width: "300px" }});
    return false;
});
```

I tried giving onClose event, i.e., (onClose: window.location.reload()) for the modal next after datacss, it is not working. May be ihave to declare onClose event somewhere else?

Thanks,

Comment: Try `onClose:location.reload(true)`

Comment: Have you tried : `onClose: window.location.reload` ?

Comment: @ling.s: can u show me how to try onclose event in my code? I tried, $('.btn').click(function(){
$('#myModalDiv').modal({ dataCss: { width: "300px" }, onClose:location.reload(true) });
    return false;
});

Modal is opening and closing at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of the [SimpleModal's](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) doc:

> The callback functions are called using the JavaScript apply function. One parameter, the dialog object, is sent, which contains the overlay, container, data and iframe objects. In addition, inside the callback, this will refer to the SimpleModal object, which will allow you to access all of the available modal elements and functions.

So when you do `onClose : window.location.reload()` , you are not passing a `function` to the `onClose` event, instead you're passing the result from calling the `reload` method of the `location` object.

This should do what you want.

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
  $('#myModalDiv').modal({
    dataCss: { width: "300px" },
    onClose : function(dialog) {
      window.location.reload();
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming above element you're going to use for closing a modal, please try this

```
$('.btn').click(function () {
    // I'm not mentioning the closing event of your modal, you've mention it before the below mentioned code
    window.top.location.reload(); // You magic code goes here!
});
```

Comment: it is not working. Means on close of the modal, i need to refresh the parent page which is not happening.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you may try this (`onClose:callback`):

```
$('#myModalDiv').modal({
    dataCss: { width: "300px" },
    onClose: function(dialog){
        location.reload(true);
    }
});
```

For more info, check [CALLBACKS](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) on project's page.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("#myModalDiv").modal({onClose: function () {
    $.modal.close();
    location.reload(true);
}});
```